# What is the proper way to handle Knex pg database errors

Tags: javascript, postgresql, error-handling, knex.js

I'm using postgres with knex javascript library to build my sql queries. I want to handle all thrown errors from postgres server, so the way I want to do this is by checking the type of the thrown error.

```
try {
   // knex query here
} catch(error) {
    if(error instanceof DatabaseError) {
      // handle pg error by checking error.code or something else
      // then send an custom error message to the client
    }

    // handle another error here which is not caused by the postgres server
}
```

Is there any way to handle the error like this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Catching Knex/DB Errors:**

You can use the `async`/`await` syntax:

```
async function() {
    try {
       await knex(/* knex query here*/)
    } catch(error) {
        if(error instanceof DatabaseError) {
          // handle pg error by checking error.code or something else
          // then send an custom error message to the client
        }
        // handle another error here which is not caused by the postgres server
    }
```

If for some reason you don't want to use that (newer) syntax, you can also chain a `.catch` ...

```
knex(/* knex query here*/)
    .then(doWhatever)
    .catch(error => {
         if(error instanceof DatabaseError) { // ...
    });
```

Alternative you can also use Knex's query-error (https://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-query-error) ... but personally I've never seen the point when the built-in promise handlers work just fine.

**(EDIT) Distinguishing PG Errors From Knex Ones:**

If you want to differentiate Knex and PG-specific errors, you can hook up an error-handler to your PG connection directly (bypassing Knex) like so:

```
function afterCreate(connection, callback) {
  connection.on("error", connectionError);
  callback(null, connection);
}

db.client.pool.config.afterCreate = afterCreate;
```

If you do that you won't need a `error instanceof DatabaseError`, because all errors caught by the `connection.on` *will* be PG errors.

You might also find this issue thread (where I got that code from) useful: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/522, as it features a discussion of error handling in Knex, and specifically handling of underlying DB errors.

**(EDIT) But How Can I Distinguish Errors *When I Catch Them*?**

Unfortunately I don't think PG errors don't have a unique prototype (ie. class) or other distinguishing feature.  You can see this by looking at an example one (from that thread I linked):

```
{"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":5432}
```

As you can see, there's no way to look that and know "that's coming from PostgreSQL", unless you start checking for specific features like `code === 'ECONNREFUSED'` (there is no `isPg: true` flag on the error).

And why doesn't Knex just intelligently identify DB errors for us?  From that same issue thread:

> It is pretty much impossible to create events like redis have for knex because of multitude of different db drivers which doesn't actually support listening for connection errors

-elhigu (Knex team member)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer but actually I'm not talking about how to catch the error I just want to know if I can check the type of Error. the idea is that I want to centralize the error handling. so is there a way to do this 'error instanceof DatabaseError'

Comment: nice but there is no way to send a reponse to the client using this hook. when I catch the error I want to check its type then send a custom error msg to the client.

Comment: Added another edit: in short, what you want doesn't exist because PG doesn't identify its own errors, and Knex (being designed to work with many DBs) doesn't know the details of errors ... because they vary by DB.

Comment: P.S. You *could* look at the error details (eg. `code === 'ECONNREFUSED'`) and respond to them, which in practical terms would probably address whatever you want to address ... unless you're specifically trying to create a custom message for "An (obscure, ie. not "connection refused") error happened in specifically in PG, and not in Knex."  But honestly, does your user really even care why their site isn't working, to that level of detail?

Comment: One final thought: if your goal is "identify when our DB is acting wonky and breaking stuff", you could also use the PG-specific error handler to set some sort of "DB_BROKE" variable in your Express server, 'causing all subsequent Knex error handlers to check that var, and send a special "DB Broke" message until that flag gets cleared.  But again, I'm not sure the work required would be justified for most sites.

Comment: I got you, the idea is just I want centralize a function that handle all errors which will receive all type of thrown errors. but since there is no way to know the instance of knex error I can just use the error.code which is type of values depending on database error.    ... thank you so much I appreciate your help